# Monitor requests from command

Tags: tcp

I wonder if there is a way to monitor which requests (TCP specifically) are made by a command when it's executed.

In particular, I'm interested in which ports are involved when the command

```
gpg --keyserver someserver --recv-key keyid
```

So I would like to monitor which TCP requests are generated by this command in particular.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Read `man strace`. Read `man gpg`. Install `wireshark`.

Comment: (1) Run `wireshark` on a "quiet" system, filter for traffic to "someserver". (2) If you suspect some other traffic is generated (which would be surprising), and you cannot reduce noisy traffic from other parts of the system, make a network namespace with veth to main network namespace, set up NAT for it, run `wireshark` on veth.

Comment: @dirk i think the second part could be a bit hard for someone not that deep into networking and *nix in general ;)

Comment: @miraunpajaro here is something related, if you just care about gpg https://serverfault.com/questions/168826/how-to-install-gpg-keys-from-behind-a-firewall

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone!